# How to draw continuous charts with gwt-visualization

Tags: java, gwt, google-api, google-visualization

I'm using [gwt-visualization](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) to display some [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/).
Everything works fine except that I can't set up a [continuous X-axis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous) for my column chart. From my understanding, I only need to define the first column of the chart to NOT be `STRING` - but I always end up with a discrete X-axis.

Here's what I do:

```
DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
dataTable.addRows(rawData.getNumberOfRows());
dataTable.addColumn(DATE, "time interval");
for (Category category : rawData.getCategories()) {
    dataTable.addColumn(NUMBER, category.getName());
}

int row = 0;
for (Date month : rawData.getMonths()) {
    dataTable.setValue(row++, 0, month);
}

// set other data for categories
```

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing? Or does the Java library not support this?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/dwBBuOYnunU

Comment: Since the question has been answered there, I'm adding the answer below so that nobody re-answers a solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/dwBBuOYnunU) by asgallant (a true hero of Google Visualization support):

asgallant's comment:

> That sounds like the wrong chart package is getting loaded.  Can you post the javascript produced by your code (open in a browser, view source, and copy it here)?

skirsch's response:

> Ah well, that was a great hint.
> It does actually load the "areachart" instead of the "corechart". Seems like the latest version available via Maven dates back to 2009, being obviously outdated.

## Answer

Make sure that you are loading the appropriate chart package, otherwise you cannot use continuous axes.